# How to enable a maintenance page on the frontend server while you are restarting the backend service?

Tags: nginx, proxy, daemon, high-availability

I am trying to improve the user experience while a backend service is down due to maintenance, shutdown manually.

We do had a frontend web proxy, which happens to be nginx but it could also be something else like a NetScaler instance. An important note is that the **frontend proxy is running on a different machine than the backend** application.

Now, for the backend service it takes a lot of time to start, even more than 10 minutes in some cases.

Note, I am asking this question on StackOverflow, as opposed to ServerFault because providing a solution for this problem is more likely to require writing some bash code inside the daemon startup script.

What we want to achive:

- `service mydaemon stop` should enable the maintenance page on the frontend proxy
- `service mydaemon start` should disabled the maintenance page on the frontend proxy

In the past we used to create a `maintenance.html` page and had nginx configured to check the existence of this page using `try`, before falling back to the backend.

Still, because we decided to move nginx to another machine we cannot do this and doing this using ssh raises security concerns.

We already considered writing this file to a NFS drive which would be accessible by both machine, but even this solution does not scale for a service that has a lot of traffic. Nginx will end-up trying this for every request, slowing down the responses quite a lot.

We are looking for another solution for this problem, one that would ideally be more flexible.

As a note, we still want to be able to trigger this behaviour from inside the daemon script of the backend application. So if the backend application stops responsing for other reasons, we do expect to see the same from the frontend.

Comment: One idea would be to open specific port on the backend server during the maintenance and setup the frontend to check for this port. Still, I don't know how to implement this and if this would scale well.